# Redux Toolkit: createAsyncThunk - rejectWithValue - TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'rejectWithValue' of '_ref2' as it is undefined."

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I've been trying to make auth refresh token calls using Redux toolkit but after installing all fixes, it still is now able to read error message.

**Setting up axios instance:**

```
export const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: REACT_APP_API_URL,
});
```

**Making API call:**

```
export const refreshAccessAndRefreshTokens = async () => {
  const response = await axiosInstance({
    method: 'post',
    url: '/refresh-tokens',
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  return response;
};
```

**Thunk function:**

```
// GET ACCESS TOKEN USING REFRESH TOKEN
export const refreshTokens = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/refreshTokens',
  async ({ rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await refreshAccessAndRefreshTokens();
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      console.log('data', error.response.data);
      console.log('message', error.response.data.message);
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);
```

**Extra reducers in auth slice:**

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(refreshTokens.pending, (state) => {
        state.loading = true;
      })
      .addCase(refreshTokens.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.isAuthenticated = true;
        state.user = action.payload.user;
        state.roles = action.payload.roles;
      })
      .addCase(refreshTokens.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.success = false;
        state.message = action.payload;
        state.isAuthenticated = false;
        state.user = null;
        state.roles = [];
      })
  },
```

I'm able to see the errors in browser console, but rejectWithMessage is not working:

**Console output:**

[image: console output]

**Redux output:**

[image: redux output]

Refresh Tokens is being called on login page through useEffect to redirect the user to where he came from in case he is already logged in.

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(refreshTokens());
    dispatch(reset());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      if (roles.find((role) => role === process.env.REACT_APP_ROLE)) {
        navigate(from, { replace: true });
      } else {
        dispatch(
          errorFn({
            success: false,
            message: 'You are not authorized to access this page!',
          })
        );
      }
    }
  }, [dispatch, from, isAuthenticated, navigate, roles]);
```

Comment: Please provide code part where you are actually calling thunk `refreshTokens`

Comment: It is the 3rd code - titled - Thunk function

Comment: Not the definition, I need to see where do you call it (eg: where is the code where you do `refreshTokesn()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument that is passed to the callback function you give to `createAsyncThunk` is the argument that you pass when you call the action.
[take a look here for more information.](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) The second argument is the `thunkAPI` which contains the `rejectWithValue`. Try putting a dummy parameter as the first parameter to the callback like this -

```
// GET ACCESS TOKEN USING REFRESH TOKEN
export const refreshTokens = createAsyncThunk(
  'auth/refreshTokens',
  async (_, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
      const response = await refreshAccessAndRefreshTokens();
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
      console.log('data', error.response.data);
      console.log('message', error.response.data.message);
      return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
export const canLogin = createAsyncThunk("AUTH/login", 
async (loginData ,{ rejectWithValue })=> {
    try{
        const response=await axios.post(AuthConfig.API_URL + AuthConfig.LOGIN_URI, loginData)
        return response
    }
    catch(error){
        if (!error.response || !error.message) 
            throw error
        return rejectWithValue(getErrorMessage(error))
    }    
  }
);

export function getErrorMessage(error) {
    return (
      error?.response?.data?.message ||
      error?.response?.data.error ||
      error?.response?.data ||
      error?.message ||
      error.toString()
    );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).